# Using vimeo API, can I get the video URL before upload is complete?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

When having users upload videos to my vimeo via a form in a WordPress blog, can vimeo return the video URL (to use in the code) before the video upload is actually finished?

Comment: Did you try to do some research yourself before asking here? Maybe searching their API documentation might give you the answer.

Comment: I did. But because I am not fluent with their API nor I am a skillful programmer, I had to know if that's possible before I dive head first into this. I searched here and through Google. Nothing like what I wanted to know came up and I believe mine will serve others with the same question in the future.

Comment: In response to the post request the vimeo API does return the video uri and upload.form parameters as mentioned in its documentation https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#form-approach 
Even when redirecting after uploading the video via POST request from form, Vimeo API redirects before the link is active! Which is very frustrating. I have to refresh and check when the video uri becomes active!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The resources required to define an upload url are all created during the completion step of an upload (in POST uploads this is the first redirect to vimeo.com, in PUT uploads this is the DELETE request).

This allows us to verify that you have uploaded a video (and not a text file, or image), and verify that the upload has completed, and is successful, before assigning a URL.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer.